# Como guardar datos en un array de Fortran

Tags: fortran

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en FORTRAN muy despacio para poder hacer mi trabajo fin de carrera. Estoy interesado en saber escribir un código que me permita almacenar datos de un fichero (.dat o .txt) a un array multidimensional. He intentado el siguiente código para un fichero que tiene 15 filas y 4 columnas, y quería que lo almacenase en una matriz de 15 x 4 a la que he llamado `matrix`:

```
program almacenararray

    implicit none

    integer :: i,j

    integer,dimension(15,4) :: matrix


    open (101,file='/Users/manuelperezescribano/Desktop/PROGRAMAS TFG/localizacionmaximosyminimos/datos.txt',status="old")


    do i=1,15
        do j=1,4
            read(101,*)
            matrix(i,j)=i+j
        end do
    end do

    close (101)


    print*,matrix(i,j)

end program almacenararray
```

Sin embargo, el resultado no es el esperado: la matriz no es impresa por pantalla, con lo que no sé si se han almacenado los datos del fichero .txt a la matriz o array correctamente. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar el error?

Gracias

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so], te invito a leer [ask]. Es necesario que además de tu duda, la cual está bien planteada, agregues el código de lo que hayas intentado y el problema o dificultad encontrada. Puedes leer [mcve] para que tengas una idea. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Tienes dos errores.

La manera en la que volcamos lo leído en el archivo a la matriz es:

```
do i = 1, 15
    do j = 1, 4
       read(101, *) matrix(i, j)
    end do
end do
```

---

Pero además la forma en la que imprimimos una matriz es elemento a elemento:

```
do i = 1, 15
    do j = 1, 4
       print*, matrix(i, j)
    end do
end do
```

Si quieres darle un formato más bonito podemos imprimir fila a fila.

```
do i = 1, 15
    print '(4I3)', (matrix(i, j), j = 1, 4)
end do
```

Con el argumento `'(4I3)'` estamos indicando que imprimiremos 4 elementos donde cada uno es un entero (`I`) de 3 caracteres.
He escogido 3 caracteres asumiendo que el entero más largo que contenga la matriz será de 2 caracteres.
De esta forma habrá un espacio de separación entre las columnas.